# Gaussian process regression vs deep learning

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process, rms, tensorflow

I have the following analytic function.

$y =e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2} \left(4 \sin^2 6 x + 3 \cos^2 x \sin^2 4 x + 1\right)$

My goal is to create $(x, y)$ pairs from this function where $x = [-2, 2]$ and use nonlinear regression to fit a curve to the data. This is for mere educational purpose.

Which one of Gaussian Process Regression and deep learning (using TensorFlow) should give me better RMSE?

Comment: Try both and see!

Comment: @Zach, I have tried and GPR is giving the better. I would like to know if it is expected.

Comment: The answer is almost always try both and see.  I don't know a lot about GPR, but I would expect tensorflow to be able to do a good job approximating a smooth function like this.  Neural nets can take a lot of learning to get right, so it's possible you just need to tune the tensorflow model more to get good results.

Comment: This question is too underspecified to say much of anything, akin to asking whether to use screws or nails in construction (either can be useful depending on context). What GP kernels? What's your computational budget? How much data? What NN architecture and transfer functions? Do you care about variance of the estimator in regions far from your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gaussian Processes will work very well and you will get a perfect interpolation of the training data as you have a deterministic function.

With deep learning you are adding so much complexity to your problem that is not actually needed and, even if it might give you a better RMSE (but this is not sure), you are wasting a lot of computational time/power for an easy task.

It would be impossible for you to justify to a reviewer why did you choose deep learning for such a simple task. Stick to Occam's rule...

If you fit a single Gaussian Process you will get a very good result. If you fit nested (deep) GPs, you will have to invert covariance matrices in every nested GP, each having a computational complexity of the order $O(N^3)$.

Comment: (+1) Seconded. When the underlying function is analytic and expressible as polynomials, exponential and trigonometric functions, a GP with a simple squared exponential kernel works *extremely* well.

Comment: @lacerbi, could you please explain why GP works very well for analytical function? Should I ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @ancillary, could you please explain what you meant by 'adding so much complexity to your problem'?

Comment: @OmarShehab: because these analytic functions are locally *extremely* well-approximated by quadratic and squared-exponential (which is locally quadratic near the peak) functions.

Comment: @OmarShehab Complexity can mean different things. For example, if you are trying to fit a polynomial to some data, and you see that a cubic one works well, there is no need to go for higher degrees like 8, 9. Of course as you increase the order of the polynomial the error decreases, but you overfit and you will incur in higher out of sample prediction errors. In linear regression complexity can mean adding too many terms. In Bayesian Hierarchical models (your case with GPs) means adding too many levels of priors. If one layer works well, there is no need to add too many hidden layers.

Comment: @ancillary, how would I know if a model is working well? For example, if I am computing RMSE, how would I know if the value is reasonable? Is there any benchmark?

Comment: @OmarShehab Hi Omar, it's hard to say a benchmark as 1) the RMSE depends on a model and every model is wrong. You can choose what is better when you compare a set of models M_1, ..., M_k. You can pick the model having the lowest between RMSE_1, ..., RMSE_k. But keep in mind that if you compare two models GPs and deep GPs, and you only get a very small improvement in RMSE using deep GPs, then there is no need to use deep GPs over a simple GP as you will need more time to get the predictions. So you would have a lower RMSE but higher computational (waiting) time. Use a simple GP and don't worry!